# How to retrieve an IxxxSettings(an IOptions<..>) before the app is built?

Tags: mongodb, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I've an Asp.Net 6 app. In one of my package I configure some services that will be available.
One of the services will require to read some configurations of my settings.

So I've created the follow settings class(and the according interface):

```
public class MongoDbSettings : IMongoDbSettings
{
    public string Host { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public string Port { get; set; }

    public string ConnectionString => $"mongodb://{UserName}:{Password}@{Host}:{Port}";
}
```

I'm registering it like this:

```
public static IServiceCollection ConfigureInfrastructureServices(this IServiceCollection services,
    IConfiguration configuration)
{
    services.Configure<MongoDbSettings>(configuration.GetSection("MongoDbSettings"));
    services.AddSingleton<IMongoDbSettings>(serviceProvider => serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<IOptions<MongoDbSettings>>().Value);

    //Here I'm trying to add some code

}
```

This IMongoDbSettings will be used at multiple place(repository and Asp.Net Identity).

Just below, I'm trying to setup [Asp.Net Core Identity for mongo db](https://github.com/matteofabbri/AspNetCore.Identity.Mongo):

```
    services.AddIdentityMongoDbProvider<User, Role, Guid>(
        identityOption => { identityOption.Password.RequiredLength = 8; },
        mongoOptions => { mongoOptions.ConnectionString = HOW TO GET THE MONGO DB CONNECTION STRING HERE });
```

But I'm not sure how I can retrieve my instance of `IMongoDbSettings`.

*Just to be clear*, I know that I can do a `configuration.GetSection("MongoDbSettings")` and then access `GetSection("username")`, but here my goal is to get my instance of `IMongoDbSettings`

Comment: Hi, I'm confused your goal here. `configuration.GetSection("MongoDbSettings")` here is common used to read the data from json file. You can give this value to `mongoOptions.ConnectionString`. But it does not have any relationship with how do you register the `IMongoDbSettings`. What is your scenario?

Comment: @Rena I would like to use the `MongoDbSettings` class, in order to validate the settings and inject the settings in other places than my startup file.